# JqueryDateTimePicker NotWorking

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
I am struggling to make datepicker work.
```

I added all the scripts and still I am not able to see datepicker when I click my textbox.
   Please correct me if I am wrong.
   My code:

```
        //<![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#datePicker').datetimepicker({
         });
     });

     $(function () {
         $('#EndDate').datetimepicker({
             duration: '',
             dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             showTime: true,
             constrainInput: false
         });
     });
  //]]>
```

My html:

```
  <p>
    Date:
    <input type="text" id="datePicker" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= Html.Label("EndDate","EndDate:")%>
        <%= Html.TextBox("EndDate") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("EndDate","*")%>
    </p>
```

Comment: Please have a look in JavaScript Error Console and post possible errors.

Comment: did you also link to the css ?

Comment: @Roger Yes I linked it

Comment: implement try catch block in document.ready and check if you get any error.

Comment: @Moniecorleone I am not getting any error in my alert

Comment: can you check your rendered markup for the controls

Comment: which datetimepicker js you are using?

Comment: @Moniecorleone <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @sk2212 I can see errors in my error console

Comment: @sk2212 It says $.datepicker is undefined

Comment: @sk2212 Thu Mar 14 2013 12:11:14
Error: $("#datePicker").datetimepicker is not a function
Source file: http://localhost:4442/
Line: 43

Comment: You also included jquery.js and jqueryui.js right?

Comment: @Moniecorleone yes I included them as well

Comment: @Moniecorleone I am missing jqueryui.js plugin . If you please do it an answer I will mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included JqueryUI.js before including datetimepicker.js.

Please check the requirements section in the following link.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

I think error is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#datePicker').datepicker();

     $('#EndDate').datepicker({
         duration: '',
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         showTime: true,
         constrainInput: false
     });
 });
```

`and be sure to load jquery ui library too after jquery.`